# an iff proof on the existence of weak derivative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have trouble understanding the following proposition.

**Proposition**

$f,g\in L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$. Then $g=D^{\alpha}f$ iff. there exists $f_m\in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ such that 
$f_m\to f$ in $L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$ and $D^{\alpha}f_m\to g$ in $L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)$.

Here is the solution I received

**Proof**:
($\Longleftarrow$) $f_m\to f$ and $D^{\alpha}f_m\to g$
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{\int_{\Omega}f_m\cdot D^{\alpha}\phi\,dx}_{\downarrow}= \underbrace{(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_{\Omega}D^{\alpha}f_m\cdot\phi\,dx}_{\downarrow} 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega}f\cdot D^{\alpha}\phi\,dx= (-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_{\Omega}D^{\alpha}g\phi\,dx 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 \left|\int_{\Omega}f_m\cdot D^{\alpha}\phi\,dx-\int_{\Omega}f\cdot D^{\alpha}\phi\,dx\right|&\le\int_{\Omega}|f_m-f| \underbrace{|D^{\alpha}\phi|}_{C}\,dx\\
 &\le C\int_{\text{sup}(\phi)}|f_m-f|dx\to 0
\end{align*}

**Q1**
I feel the solution is incomplete for the part $(\Longleftarrow)$. Also, base on the above equations, there is no explaination provided. I became quite lost on what is going on. Could any one help providing a complete solution for the part $(\Longleftarrow)$, or add some explaination on the above?

---

**Q2**
By the way, here is based don my understanding...but I am afraid I am wrong. Thanks for any corrections.

($\Longleftarrow$)
Suppose there exists such a sequence $\{f_m\}$ then by assumptions,
\begin{align*}
 f_m&\to u\quad\text{in}\quad\text{in}\quad L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)\\
 D^{\alpha}f_m&\to g\quad\text{in}\quad\text{in}\quad L_{\text{loc}}^1(\Omega)
\end{align*}
By the definition of weak derivatives, we have
\begin{align*}
 \int_{\Omega}f D^{\alpha}\varphi\,dx&=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_{\Omega}D^{\alpha}f\cdot\varphi\,dx\\
 \int_{\Omega}u D^{\alpha}\varphi\,dx&=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_{\Omega}g\varphi\,dx
\end{align*}
To match the rhs of above, we have
    For $p=1$, 
    \begin{align*}
&\  \left|\int_{\Omega}g(x)\varphi(x)dx-\int_{\Omega}D^{\alpha}f(x)\varphi(x)\right|\\
&\le \left|\int_{\Omega}(g(x)-D^{\alpha}f(x))\varphi(x)\right|\\
&\le \int_{\Omega}\left|g(x)-D^{\alpha}f(x)\right||\varphi(x)|dx\\
&\le C \int_{\Omega}\left|g(x)-D^{\alpha}f(x)\right|dx
 \end{align*}
as $m\to\infty$, where $C=\sup_{\Omega}|\varphi(x)|<\infty.$

Now to match the lhs, we have
    For $p=1$, 
    \begin{align*}
&\  \left|\int_{\Omega}f(x)D^{\alpha}\varphi(x)dx-\int_{\Omega}u_m(x)D^{\alpha}\varphi(x)\right|\\
&\le \left|\int_{\Omega}(f(x)-u_m(x))D^{\alpha}\varphi(x)\right|\\
&\le \int_{\Omega}\left|f(x)-u_m(x)\right||D^{\alpha}\varphi(x)|dx\\
&\le C' \int_{\Omega}\left|f(x)-u_m(x)\right|dx
 \end{align*}
as $m\to\infty$, where $C'=\sup_{\Omega}|D^{\alpha}\varphi(x)|<\infty.$

---

I understood that the downarrow mean D.C.T.. But I need more detail. Would be appreciate if someone could help filling up the gap. I added my own solution which I doubt there could contain lots of mistakes.

Comment: Re Q1, based on context it seems that $\phi$ is $C^\infty$ with compact support. $f_m$ in $L^1_{\rm loc}$ thus implies $f_mD^\alpha \phi \in L^1$ for any $\alpha$.  Probably the $\downarrow$'s in the displayed equation are correct based on the dominated convergence theorem, although details are unclear. For the rest of the displayed equation, $|D^\alpha \phi|$ is bounded by some $C$, again because $\phi$ is $C^\infty$ with compact support.  $\int_{\sup(\phi)} |f-f_m|$ goes to zero as $m\to\infty$ because, I guess, that is what it means for $f_m$ to converge to $f$ in $L^1_{\rm loc}$.

Comment: @ForgotALot : Please see my edited answer.

Comment: I think your argument makes sense now.

Comment: I always feel something not quite right, still, any corrections is appreciated